# Summation signs in maximum likelihood (ridge regression example)

Tags: maximum-likelihood, ridge-regression, notation

I can't find how to deal with summation signs ($\sum$) when performing maximum likelihood estimation. I've encountered it in ridge regression:
$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (y_i-\theta^Tx_i)^2 + \lambda\sum_{i=j}^n \theta_i^2$

For instance in the penalty term expression:

$\lambda\sum_{i=1}^n \theta_i^2$

How do I with $\sum$ then?

Is it like;
$\prod_{i = 1}^{n}(\lambda\sum_{i=1}^n \theta_i^2) = n\lambda \sum_{i=1}^n \theta_i^{2n}$

And then to take $\log(\theta)$ of it I do(?);

$ \log(n\lambda) + 2n\log(\sum_{i=1}^n \theta_i)$

My attempt on the full expression;

Likelihood:

$p(y/\theta) =\prod_{i = 1}^{n}(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (y_i-\theta^Tx_i)^2 + \lambda\sum_{i=j}^p \theta_j^2) = \frac{1}{n^n} \sum_{i=1}^n (y_i-\theta^Tx_i)^{2n} +n\lambda \sum_{i=1}^n \theta_i^{2n}$

Logs:

$log(p(y/\theta)) = \log(\frac{1}{n^n})+2n\log(\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i-\theta^Tx_i)) + \log(n\lambda)+2n\log(\sum_{i=1}^n\theta_i)$

Derivative ($\theta$):

$\frac{d}{d\theta}\log(p(y/\theta)) = \frac{2n}{\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i-\theta^Tx_i)}+\frac{2n}{\sum_{i=1}^n\theta_i}$

To put it in a context I've been reading about ridge regression and found this piece of code on how to implement loglikelihood of ridge regression, but as you can see I don't end up with the same expression.

```
  # LogLikelihood = log P(Y|X,w,sigma)
  Loglikelihood = function(x,y,w,sigma){
  wTX = as.matrix(x)%*%w
  loss = sum((wTX - as.matrix(y))^2)
  N = dim(x)[1]
  t1 = (N*0.5*(log(sigma)))
  t2 = (N*0.5*log(2*pi))
  t3 = (sigma*0.5*loss)
  logLik = t1-t2 - t3
  return(logLik)
  }
```

Comment: The expression $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (y_i-\theta^Tx_i)^2 + \lambda\sum_{i=j}^n \theta_i^2$ is already on the log-likelihood scale. $\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i-\theta^Tx_i)^2$ is -2 times the Gaussian log-likelihood (up to constants).

Comment: @ThomasLumley would you like to elaborate? Should I just take the derivative of the expression and set it to zero directly?